# How to convert to a Lighter wight Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop

Tags: lubuntu, desktop-environments, ram, disk-usage, cpu-load

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 Desktop and I'm happy with it. However sometime I think the older versions were better as they were lighter or utilized less resources.

Is there any way that, it will ask me during every boot time to choose a different settings or *GUI* (maybe) so that it will utilize less resources. I don't want to uninstall/loose anything permanently.

Note: Again I am happy with my current full featured Ubuntu Desktop.

I have read about Lubuntu, can I put it beside/within my current Ubuntu installation without loosing anything?  It will appreciate if there is any other better idea.

Comment: First of all Ubuntu 13.04 is no more supported and does not receive any security updates so vulnerable. you should upgrade to a newer version. You can always use `gnome-session-fallback` to get an interface similar to older versions. It will ask you to choose between fallback session and unity at the time of log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can!! :D

Just head to the software centre and type "LXDE" and install it. (LXDE is Lubuntu!! Consider it another name for the same thing.)

This will make you able to choose between "Unity" (which is the default desktop you know about) and LXDE which is awesome and lightweight.

[image: how to switch desktop environments]

You see that white circle with the Ubuntu logo in it? (above) Just click on it to choose between Unity and LXDE!!

**You won't lose any features and you can use Unity again whenever you want!** A desktop environment is just a selection of programs (such as a different windows manager, a different files manager, a different audio player and so...)

The one and only thing you wouldn't like is that it's ugly! XD but there are forums that describe how to make it look more similar to Unity. It's super fast and I use it by default. :)

*...ah yes! A word about Ubuntu 13.04. It's outdated and not supported anymore!! But luckily you can upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10 very simply through the update manager. (The window that usually pops up asking for updates). It'd ask you if you want to upgrade to 13.10 so you just accept the upgrade and you're totally done!! :D*

Comment: Thanks every one.. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with LXDE, GMONE MetaCity & Compiz as well as Cinnamon. Everyday I am finding something new, exciting. I have also installed Ubuntu in my android mobile. However that did not worked very well. But for sure: UBUNTU IS FUN

Comment: and that's what it's all about :D